# How to improve search time in OpenLDAP with back-sql and Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, ldap, openldap

I recently switched my openldap backend from HDB to back-sql and PostgreSQL. I slightly modified the back-sql rdbms/postgres database schema files provided in OpenLDAP to create my database and mappings. I'm basically only using persons and organizational units to create my tree structure. However, I have noticed that searches performed from PHPLDAPAdmin and other tools are very slow. When clicking on an ou object that has 535 persons under it, simply displaying the ou attributes will take seconds as opposed to milliseconds with HDB. When viewing all children for the OU and retrieve the 535 objects, it takes 0.08 seconds with HDB, as opposed to 6.19 seconds with Postgres and the back-sql.
Is there a way to improve  this performance limitation with Postgres? Are there configurations to enable in openldap? The Postgres database itself?

Thank you,

Comment: `I slightly modified the back-sql rdbms/postgres database schema` Maybe you forgot some PK/FK constraints or indexes. Best way to find out is to (temporally) log_statements and dig up the resulting queries from the pg logfiles. Adding your schema (changes) and the resulting queries to the question might help, too.

Comment: As with any database, the columns you use in search tests should be indexed.